# Jquery slideToggle, 2 buttons, 2 panels, 2 images

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have a site with a particular effect I'm trying to create. I'm at the very early stages of learning query so would love some direction/help/code to achieve what I need...

I have 2 buttons (images) - #toggle1 and toggle#2.

Each button has its own hide/show panel (simple divs) called #panel1 and #panel2.

I can use 2 simple separate slidetoggle scripts to make the relevant button open and close its relevant panel. However, how do I combine these scripts so only one panel is open at any one time (starting with neither open)?

Then, the buttons I am using are images, how can I get the images to change to different images (like a + image to open and x image to close) when they are clicked?

I have done lots of research and can find ways of achieving all these things separately but need to know the best practice to get it all together...

Comment: You forgot to show us your HTML, and any attempt(s) you might have made. Please add your relevant ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) code into your question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't feel it relevant in this case as its just two images and two divs. As explained, I can do a simple slidetoggle but I know this is not the right way so felt it would be worthless for anyone to see. Thank you for your comment though, I've taken it on board.

Comment: Except you've completely missed the point and failed to add your code to a question about, essentially, DOM manipulation/behaviour.

Comment: David, I explained I was very new and assumed the example was a simple one to understand, if I have offended you then that was not my intention. 
If you take a look at @Null comments below, they have grasped not only my problem but also my limited ability. They've adapted their learning style to help me and has actually made a difference to how I will go about learning jquery and getting it to work for me.
If I post my markup for 2 images and 2 divs will you help me too?

Comment: My intention isn't to embarrass, or pester you, it's to make this question easier for people to visualise what's happening. You *describe* your code to us, the easiest way is to *show* us the (stripped-down, *minimal*) code because it's less ambiguous, and less prone to misunderstanding. It *also* helps us to point out any errors you might be making with your (beginner?) knowledge of HTML, which should further promote your learning. We ask for *code* because that's what we work with, it's how we work and it's how we can better teach.

Comment: Ok David, I appreciate your time. @Null has given me something to stat with on this and should I need any more help I'll make sure I post my code :o)

Answer (score 1):

1) Keep a global variable that determines what panel is currently open.

```
var leftPanelOpen = false;
```

2) When a button is pressed, determine what to do accordingly

```
$("#leftPanelButton").click(function() {
    if(!leftPanelOpen) {
        //Left panel was not open previously. close right panel and open left
        $("#rightPanel").slideUp(500, function() {
            $("#leftPanel").slideDown(500);
        });
    }

    leftPanelOpen = true;
});

$("#rightPanelButton").click(function() {
    if(leftPanelOpen) {
        //Left panel open previously. close left and open right
        $("#leftPanel").slideUp(500, function() {
            $("#rightPanel").slideDown(500);
        });
    }

    leftPanelOpen = false;
});
```

3) On your click events, change the images accordingly. This really depends on what you actually want to do. If on your click event you want to change the button image itself, then do just that

```
$(this).attr("background-image", "url('...');");
```

As other poster suggests you can do both click calls to one function but when just beginning I wouldn't really bother.

To do this properly, you would need to initialize the right panel as being open first. If you want the left panel to open initially, initialize the global to true.

Comment: On reading this makes perfect sense. I will try this later tonight. I am not familiar with 'if' yet but seems very straightforward. How about getting the button images to change? Would you just have a separate script (there's loads of examples on the web) and run that too?

Comment: Inside of the $("#leftPanelButton").click call the $(this).attr("background-image"), "url()"); If you are unfamiliar with if's, don't take this wrong way, you may want to take a couple steps back and learn some basic javascript. Knowing arithmetic operations, blocks, conditional statements, etc is very important to any programming.

Comment: Completely agree with the step back comment! No offence taken! I just wanted to know the best way to combine all this so I was not learning things that would not get me to my ultimate goal. I really appreciate you help and the way you've explained everything. I'll have a go later and set it as the correct answer then. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you ask many questions, I think one at the time.

You can assign the same function to your div's and include a variable, then execute the script.

```
    <button id="toggle1" onClick="open('1');"></button>
    <div id="panel1" style="display:none;">Content</div>

    <button id="toggle2" onClick="open('2');"></button>
    <div id="panel2" style="display:none;">Content</div>

    <script>
        function open(num){
            jQuery("#panel"+num).slideToggle();
        }
    </script>
```

In that way you can use the same function with both divs.